# Sharing dependencies between independent Play 2 projects in SBT?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm developing a website with Play 2 and I'm having some troubles with dependencies. I searched in the documentation but found nothing relevant.

Here is the structure of my project:

- `api` - a Play 2 application that contains my models, services, controllers, etc.
- `commons` - a Play 2 application that provide some utility classes, paypal integration, etc.

I added a dependency for `commons` in `api` in `api/build.sbt`. In `commons` I added the following dependency for PayPal:

```
"com.paypal.sdk" % "rest-api-sdk" % "0.7.1"
```

I thought that I had to add this dependency only in `commons`. But when I use the classes interacting with PayPal in `api`, I have `ClassNotFound` errors.

Is SBT not supposed to retrieve dependencies of `commons` when adding a dependency to `commons` in `api`?

If I add the dependency to PayPal in `api/build.sbt`, everything works, but I have this dependency in both places.

**EDIT for Jacek questions**

- Play 2 Version : 2.2.0
- `api` and `commons` are two standalone SBT project (no root project)
- Dependency between `api` and `commons` in `api/build.sbt` :

> ```
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>     // Other dependencies ...
>     "com.mycompany" %% "commons" % "1.0.0"
> )
> ```

Comment: What exact version of Play do you work with? Are `api` and `commons` two standalone SBT projects with no parent/root SBT project? How did you define the dependency between `commons` and `api`? Could you run `tree` or something similar to show the project structure? I'm mostly interested in directories with `build.sbt` and `project/*.scala` files inside.

Comment: I edited the question, here is a pastebin of `play dependencies`: http://pastebin.com/kxRS1tdK

Answer (score 0):

Given

- *"`api` and `commons` are two standalone SBT project (no root project)"* and
- *"Dependency between `api` and `commons` in `api/build.sbt`"* via `libraryDependencies` with no Ivy scopes.

Then

- the `api` project shares `compile` dependencies of the `commons` project **in**+transitively.

Please note that since you *"use the classes interacting with PayPal in `api`"* you've **direct** dependency on PayPal classes in the `api` project and hence you must add the PayPal  dependency to the project's `libraryDependencies`. They are separate projects with their own build configuration (and dependencies), and regardless of the dependencies of one the other should declare its own properly.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using `PayPal` classes directly in `api`. I'm calling only methods in `commons`. But these methods are calling `PayPal` classes. There is no way to make `api` sharing dependencies transitively with `commons` ?